# nodejs script not running in crontjob

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, cron

Hello I would like to add a nodejs script to cronjob and I can't seem to get it working.. I am using shell to call the node script. I have tried making another nodejs script to test if its working, I mean if I had the paths wrong but that one is working.

runScript

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date +%s` >> /path/cron.log
/usr/bin/node /path/main.js >> /path/cron.log
```

runScript1

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date +%s` >> /path/cron.log
/usr/bin/node /path/test.js >> /path/cron.log
```

and in cron:

```
0       *       *       *       *       /path/runScript
0       *       *       *       *       /path/runScript1
```

So to recap I get both dates printed in the cron.log but only the test.js file runs after, the main.js is not running. When I tried to run manually like this ./runScript it worked.

Comment: has cron user right to access to `/path/test.js` and `/path/cron.log`?

Comment: just make sure the cron (may be root in some cases) user is able to access the `/path`

Comment: Yes, both shell scripts and both js scripts have same permissions, and are able to write to the log file. I mean test.js/runScript1 and main.js/runScript are in same folder with same permissions, and they both write the `echo date` to the cron but only the test runs the node script

Comment: and make sure that the node has been setup for the cron user.

Comment: what says the `su crontab <<'EOF'
/usr/bin/node /path/main.js >> /path/cron.log
EOF`?

Comment: or this: `sudo su -c '/usr/bin/node /path/main.js >> /path/cron.log' crontab`

Comment: It has root permissions but anw since the test.js runs ok, I believe it's not that the problem..

Comment: add the `crontab` user to the (for example) `adm` group as: `usermod -a -G adm crontab`, and assign the group to the folder `chown :adm /path`. add write permisstion for group: `chmod g+w /path` and retry: `sudo su -c '/usr/bin/node /path/main.js >> /path/cron.log' crontab`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Thanks for trying but I'm telling you it's not a permission problem since I created a test js/shell script with same permissions and that one works ok..

Comment: it can be a permisstion problem, because inside the `main.js` the code can try accessing to unpermitted area, while the `test.js` can't

Comment: so have you tried to simulate the crontab run from within console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the problem was the NodeJS Modules path inside the script, so the Bash and Cron were ok!